# How to make block with list of terms from blog postings

Tags: views, blocks, nodes

I would like to display a navigational block in a sidebar on a single-user blog page which will have a listing of all taxonomy terms used in the blog entries.

I am using a custom content type and Views to make the blog. I have set up a vocab for this content type, with multiple terms from this vocab selectable for each posting.

I set up a block display in the view with a field using *Taxonomy: All terms*. Then a filter limited to my specific vocab. Everything is fine, except that I am getting duplicate terms in the list, as some blog entries have the same terms.

Can anyone please tell me how to remove the duplicate results, or tell me a better way to get what I want?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you have created a view of nodes, and using the *Taxonomy: All terms* field to display the terms of those nodes. That approach will indeed produce duplicate results.

Instead, you need to create a view of Taxonomy Terms. I don't know which versions you are using, but here is the export of such a View made with Drupal 7  & Views 7.x-3.0-rc1.

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'tags';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = '';
$view->base_table = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$view->human_name = 'Tags';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0-alpha1';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Tags';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_taxonomy'] = 1;
/* Sort criterion: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['name']['field'] = 'name';
/* Filter criterion: Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['id'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_vocabulary';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['field'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['value'] = array(
  'tags' => 'tags',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'tags';
```